# Plumbing issue...perhaps venting problem

Tags: plumbing

So my bathroom sink was draining slowly. This seems to be a constant issue with this sink..I have poured liked plumber down it numerous times and it works for a week or so and then needs to be done again. This time I was having no luck with the chemicals. I took the trap off and it was pretty funky. Cleaned it and I think I have everything together correctly but it seems like it is draining even slower now...any suggestions? This photo shows how the trap was put back together except that the two joints are much closer together, like basically touching[image]

Comment: That's a new arrangement to me.. Can you take a picture further down to where the pipe exits the cabinet?

Comment: New construction or addition? You must ensure there is an air vent pipe somewhere in the system. Without it, it will drain slowly, and most likely make noise. Is it "gurgling" as it drains slowly?

Comment: Did you clean the tail piece (the metal part where the stopper assembly is housed) when you had the trap off? They're much more likely to clog than traps because the stopper mechanism already obstructs the pipe.

Comment: I did clean the tail piece as well. That is where I think the problem may be. It seems to drain slower after cleaning that part. I took it completely off and thoroughly cleaned it. I’m thinking the problem may be with how I reassembled it. Is that possible?

Comment: it looks like the trap is installed upside down,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a larger clog farther down that sink drain. Try another large dose of drain cleaner down that sink, then let it sit 6-8 hrs with no water use.  After 6-8 hrs chase it with several minutes of hot water.  This added soak time has cleared several slow drains for me. If this doesn't work you may have to snake the drains, working from that sink downward.

Comment: I did indeed have a larger clog further down. I ended up calling a plumber and he used a power auger to clear it. Took him 10 minutes....I was at it for three days!!!

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a DIY or (cheap) trap. As it will work the same even if the ends are swapped , I might look at the sink itself.

Not long ago I found a sink that had clear drains and a good vent but was draining slowly.

I filled the sink with hot water until it started to slow then used a toilet plunger , what pumped out of the sink vent was so gross, i don’t want to say what it looked like but after a couple of plunges it started draining better. I had cleared the trap and drain with a small power auger, it was only after plunging that the in sink vent cleared and it drained well, after it started draining I filled it to the sink vent level and let it run on hot for a while to make sure it it was clear. 
This is in a rental so I don’t know what was plugging the sink vent and it was my first experience like this but a plunger with hot water may help you as it did me. Once the vent started to clear I plugged it with my finger while plunging prior to over flowing to the vent for everything I did. Hope this helps.